# Show Custom field in SharePoint form based from a table in sql server

Tags: jquery, web-services, sql-server

I hope I can get some tips here.
I have some fields in a SharePoint form that I would like to  pre populate from a table in SQL server tables.

So for example if I select a value in a dropdown field in sharepoint form I would like this to go to a table in SQL and get some data rows which I will then use to fill in some text in my texboxes etc...

Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [pretty good guide.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-database-as-a-data-source-3a563b0c-75e4-4856-847f-9a8182708c66?CorrelationId=e78c4c8f-62dd-4bc8-ab71-cba279456b6f&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

You can specify which columns to show, specify custom queries, order, filter, join...

Furthermore, you could also use the SSRS integration package to display it in a more BI-friendly manner... but if all you want is to expose SQL through a SharePoint list, the link above will do.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Manish as I said I want to populate texboxes, dropdown from sql server table.
Hope this makes sense